# Variables casting performance

Tags: c#, .net, performance, casting

Which code executes faster and why

```
((Form)controls.Owner).Text = langfile.ReadString(
       FormName, ((Form)controls.Owner).Name, ((Form)controls.Owner).Text);
```

or

```
Form form = (Form)controls.Owner;
form.Text = langfile.ReadString(FormName, form.Name, form.Text);
```

Comment: Have you actually tried this?

Comment: The answer is "who cares?". The second one is easier to read, and that far outweighs any tiny performance benefit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The second form may be *very slightly* faster (only one execution-time check instead of three) but that's almost certainly going to be insignificant.

However, the *readability* of the second is much *much* better than the first - so go with the second form, for that reason. Your order of development should be:

- Write the cleanest, most maintainable code you can
- Measure the code to find out if it performs well enough
- If it doesn't, profile it to find out where the time is being spent
- If profiling doesn't suggest a change in design (which it often will), then *and only then* should you micro-optimize code into a less readable form

Comment: And what about memory consuption for variables ?

Comment: @Ask: No difference, or *possible* one extra reference on the stack. Insignificant.

Answer (score 2):

You should definitely use the second version:

- much more readable
- shorter
- no redundant casting.

There **isn't any advantage with the first version**.

Comment: Does compiler optimize somehow that redundant casting?

Comment: @Ask I don't know. But the benefit of the readability is much more important that micro-optimizations, especially for UI related operations...

Answer (score 0):

Althoug I'm not a compiler expert it's pretty obvious that the two expressions will be converted to almost the same IL code, so the performance gain, if any, will be insignificant.